# UIView doesn't appear as subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a cell with subviews.

I can't figure out why the UIView `boom` isn't visible.  Here is my code:

```
let separator: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return view
}()

let boom: UIView = {
    let b = UIView()
    b.backgroundColor = .red
    return b
}()

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(separator)
    addSubview(setNumberView)
    addSubview(boom)

    backgroundColor = .orange

    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-20-[v0]", views: boom)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-20-[v0]", views: boom)

    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: separator)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(10)]|", views: separator)
```

`separator` shows up as it is supposed to.  Is there a bug in my xcode or something?  I have tried restarting xcode, putting the view into a frame, and changing the cell size.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your cell with visual debugger (here is a quick tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6 if you haven't used this before) ? It may make it easier to locate your view and see whats wrong with your layout.

Comment: You are not setting any width or height to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting any width or height to your view.

To properly setup the position of a view, you have to specify the horizontal position, the vertical position, the width and height.

The `separator` correctly specifies all of them, the `view` is missing constraints for `width` and `height`.

A way to fix that could be for example:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-20-[v0]-20-|", views: boom)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-20-[v0(100)]", views: boom)
```